# How to sort data in the file using script?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sort

I have a file `logs.txt` with numbers which repeat:

```
1   QWE
1   ASD 
1   QWE
1   QWE
1   QWE
1   qwe
12
22  qwe
2   aaa
2   vcc
2   xxx
4   asa
44  qwe
4   gfd
4   bcx
5
6   kuy
7
76  lol
5
4   ggg
23
2   ttt
34
5
5
76
5
6
78
99
8
88
7
6
88
88
88
88  wer
88  tyu
99  dsf
78  dfg
78  fgh
78
78  qwe
6   qwe
5
22  qwe
```

I need to sort them. So the highest should be on top.
example: number 1 repeats 20 times, number2 repeats 44 times...

```
20 1
44 2
1  3
5  4 
.....
```

I run this commands:

```
awk '{print $1}' logs.txt >> log2.txt

cat log2.txt | uniq -c >> log3.txt

sort -n srp >> log4.txt

tac log4.txt > log5.txt
```

It works for me but it took much time! I want to put all commands in the file to execute.
I need to create a script!

Comment: Your requirements (*"highest should be on top"*) don't match with what you show as result where the lowest comes first. - Please clarify; shall the first or second column be sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need:

```
sort -rnk1 file | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -c | sort -nk2
```

or if you only have number in first field:

```
sort -rnk1 file | tr -cs 0-9 '[\n*]' | uniq -c | sort -nk2
```

Comment: No it gives me not the result which I want. I think we need to change `tr -cs 0-9 '[\n*]'` thing.

Comment: @Invoker: What did you get when running above command?

Comment: @Invoker; Note that @cuonglm's suggestion creates (with your sample data) equivalent results if compared to the results of the suggestion in my own answer. So I assume that both our solutions work correctly. Please re-inspect your data source.

Comment: well it works but how to make it now from the most repeating to less repeating(example:  number 1 repeats 20 time , number 2 repeats 15 times, number 3 repeats 10 times. . .sort them according to repeating score. Number which had been repeating most should be on top

Comment: @Invoker: Use `sort -rnk1` instead of `sort -nk2`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! You are the best!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution, based just on `awk` and `sort`:

```
awk '{a[$1]++} END{for(i in a)print a[i],i}' logs.txt | sort -k2n
```

Comment: yes it works but how to sort (example: number 1 repeats 20 time , number 2 repeats 15 times, number 3 repeats 10 times. . .)? sort them according to repeating score. Number which had been repeating most should be on top.

Comment: @Invoker; Then sort on the first key, and reverse the sorting: `sort -k1nr`.

Answer (score 3):

GNU `awk` allows array traversal order control via `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`, so

```
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"}; {a[$1]++}; 
END{for (k in a) print k, a[k]}' logs.txt
```

Comment: No it shows me not what I want.

Comment: @Invoker, in that case you perhaps do not have GNU `awk`. What does `awk --version` say?